# Seek in string and inserting text

Tags: python-3.x

I have positions in list. These tell where to insert something in string.
string is for example:

```
s = "Hello World and foo bar"
```

List of positions:

```
list = ['0', '5', '23']
pos = list[0], etc.
```

I will insert these:

```
ins_list = ['BIG', 'BAD', 'WOLF']
```

result:

```
result = BIGHelloBAD World and foo barWOLF
```

When I was using file, I just file.seek(pos), but when I want to write it in string I cant use seek. Is there equivalent method?

Thanks, 
(maybe I have counted positions wrong, but thats not an issue here)

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable so the approach with seek/write won't work. Use slices.

Answer (score 1):

If the positions are not integers (as in your case), they must be converted to integers.  I have used integers in the pos_list:

```
s = "Hello World and foo bar"
pos_list = [0, 5, 23]
ins_list = ['BIG', 'BAD', 'WOLF']

p1 = 0
lst = []
for p2, text in zip(pos_list, ins_list):
    lst.append(s[p1:p2])
    lst.append(text)
    p1 = p2
lst.append(s[p1:])
result = ''.join(lst)

print(result)
```

The zip() takes two or more sequences and returns couples (tuples) with corresponding elements.  The strings are immutable as randcoder mentioned.  When you modify a string, you actually create a new, modified one.  Because of that the usual practice is to collect the string fragments in a list.  Finally, the list is joined to the result string.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks randcoder, slices work like a charm:

```
...loop:

part1 = s[:pos]
part2 = s[pos:]
s = part1 + ins_list[n] + part2
```

Comment: but the problem here is that in your case, you'll end up with this string `'BIGHeBADllo World and fWOLFoo bar'` and not the result you showed.